# How to pull the apk file from appcenter and get it installed on android device instead of manually downloading and storing in local and installing

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, apk, visual-studio-app-center

For automation testing purposes presently I am downloading the latest build from appcenter and storing it in my local. And in the script I am getting it installed on the android device. But this will not workout when I want to run the script through pipeline.
Is there any way to get the apk downloaded directly from appcenter and have it installed into the device.

Comment: Did you find how to download apk through api, we also want to do end-to-end test and it will be easier if we can install it on a virtual device without having to do the whole log in flow with google and appcenter web app like if it was a normal user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Center is a continuous integration, delivery, and testing solution for Android, iOS, macOS, and Windows apps. App Center let developers to ship apps faster and with more confidence by automating the development life cycle.

You can't directly download from app center and install it to android device. But you can upload your application binary package to app center and distribute it. You can distribute releases to individual testers or groups of testers. Azure DevOps uses the [App Center Distribute Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/app-center-distribute) for this.

Check [Build, test, and deploy Android apps - Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android) document for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful in your case if you would like to upload the build from app center and run your test on real device or simulator:

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/integrations/app-center